# OpenXmlElement how to know it's value is Date / DateTime

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm reading an Excel spreadsheet (xlsx) using OpenXmlDocument, I have some Date cells formated as DD/MM/YYYY, But when try to read it all i have back is a float like this **42457.670138888891** I was looking into **cell.DataType** but it is always null.

I have two questions refered to this:

1- How do I know that current cell is Date / DateTime formatted or How to know is Date type ?

2- How to convert **42457.670138888891** to c# DateTime?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176832/reading-a-date-from-xlsx-using-open-xml-sdk

Comment: This may also help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42390713/openxml-sdk2-5-excel-how-to-determine-if-a-cell-contains-a-numeric-value/42492723#42492723

Comment: Neither of the comments answer the question, though. Azar's just says how to convert the numeric value to a date and petelids' just says that you have to rely on the style to determine if the number is a date or not.  How do you know if a value is a date or not if it's type is just Number?